# how to make jquery toggle action go over all my content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a jquery toggler on the very top of my page that will eventually open up to reveal a form. The problem is that when the panel expands it will push down all the content under it instead of the panel going over the content. How do I make sure the panel expands over the content instead of pushing it down?

I only have the basic slidetoggle function set up:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
div.panel,p.flip
{
margin:0px;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.panel
{
height:120px;
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="panel">
<p>this will be a form</p>
</div>

<p class="flip">sign up!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something with `position:absolute`.

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/partkyle/2KQRu/).

Comment: can I do this without position:absolute? When I zoom in or out with position absolute, the tab will not scale with the page.

Answer (score 4):

As partkyle said, use absolute positioning, and you will probably also want to also use z-index "layering" in your css to specify which element shows on top.